# Firefox removes web component properties when appended inside iframe

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, web-component

I am trying to append a web component DOM node `comp` with a property `myprop` inside an iframe.

```
const frame = document.createElement('iframe')
frame.src = 'about:blank'

frame.addEventListener('load', _ => {
   console.log(comp.myprop) // "abc"
   frame.contentDocument.body.appendChild(comp)
   console.log(comp.myprop) // undefined in Firefox, "abc" in Chrome, Safari
})
```

This works perfectly in Chrome and Safari. However, Firefox seems to delete `myprop` after `comp` is appended to the body of the iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome and Firefox don't have the same interpretation of the Custom Element definition scope.

With Chrome, when you move a custom element from the main document to an inner `<iframe>`, it remains a (defined) custom element with all its methods and properties.

With Firefox, when you move a custom element from the main document to an inner `<iframe>`, because of frame isoation, the custom element is undefined in the context of the Frame, the element is an *unknown* tag with no custom property or custom method.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to store the value of comp.myprop in some different variable and re-assign it on comp after adding comp to the iframe. Something like this:

```
frame.addEventListener('load', _ => {
  console.log(comp.myprop);
  var propStorage = comp.myprop;

  frame.contentDocument.body.appendChild(comp);

  //You might need to add if(comp.myprop === undefined) here
  comp.myprop = propStorage;
  console.log(comp.myprop);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Firefox is broken, (in more than just this way, in case you wondered why their market share is a shadow of it's former self), but you can work around this particular problem by restoring the prototype in the adoptedCallback of the class definition.

```
adoptedCallback()
{
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this,savedConstructor.prototype);
}
```

You can't use the generic `this.constructor.prototype` as it's been reset, so you have to use an explicit reference to the prototype.